# Django Form Customisation

Tags: css, django

I am using django forms and everything is working nicely, with help from the experts on here.  Now I want to apply some formatting to the form.  As it stands I have the following fields:

```
team1 = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=StraightredTeam.objects.none(), empty_label=None)
team2 = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=StraightredTeam.objects.none(), empty_label=None)
```

They currently display as:

Team1:
"Dropdown box with all the current football teams"
Team2:
"Dropdown box with all the current football teams"

Is it easy to have the two fields side by side and fix the length of the field?

Many thanks in advance, Alan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can customize it with css. If you're using something like this `{{form}}` in your template to display the form, you can split it up into `{{form.team1}}` and `{{form.team2}}` to place them side by side. You can then give them a class attribute through a widget in your form. For example:

```
team1 = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=StraightredTeam.objects.none(), 
                               empty_label=None, 
                               widget=forms.Select(attrs={"class":"select-format"})
```

And style further using css:

```
<style>
.select-format{
    /* For example... */
    width: 100%
}
</style>
```

Any field passed into the `attrs` [dictionary](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.Widget.attrs) will be displayed in the produced HTML, and css is the way to customize it further.